# While using mpv as back-end of Smplayer, I can't use vdpau in videos.

Tags: video, smplayer

While I choose mpv as the back-end of smplayer, the hardware acceleration of video (vdpau) can't be used in the video and falls down to the software decoding.

Meanwhile, if I choose mplayer as the back-end of smplayer, the same video can be decoded via vdpau.

Moreover, if I use cli to play the same video via mpv, the video can also be decoded via vdpau.

So, how to make mpv work well with hardware acceleration when it is used as a back-end of Smplayer?

Answer (score 0):

From [official SMplayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/first-steps.php) article:

If you have trouble to play HD videos you can improve performance by following these advices:

- If you have a multicore processor: select *Preferences* in the *Options* menu. That will open the preferences dialog. Go to the *Performance* section. Now increase the *"threads for decoding"* according to the number of cores of your processor (If you have 2 cores, select 2 threads. If you have 4 cores, you can select up to 4 threads, and so on).
- If you don't have a multicore processor: select *Preferences* in the *Options* menu. That will open the preferences dialog. Go to the *Performance* section. Check the option *"Allow frame drop"*. This will help to keep *A/V sync*, although with some video formats it can cause video corruption. You can also experiment with the *H.264* *"loop filter"* option.

In addition, when playing HD videos for the best performance it is recommended to have at least up to 2GB of RAM installed on your system PC and video card with more than 384MB of memory available.

Answer (score 0):

Set in `smplayer` preferences:

- General -> Output driver : **vdpau**
- Performance -> Hardware decoding: **vdpau**

If `mpv` doesn't use hardware decoding by default add this to `~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf`

```
vo=vdpau
hwdec=vdpau
```

`vdpau` hardware decoding works fine in `mpv` and `smplayer`  on a Radeon 4xxx (r600/r700) with these settings